# What does "past exam papers were not made available for the multiple choice examination" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "past exam papers were not made available for the multiple choice examination" mean? Does it mean the past exam paper will not be on this exam and it is not worth looking at it? Or the past exam result will not be taken into account for this coming exam?

Answer (score 2):

It means neither of these things.

To 'make something available' is to provide access to it so that you can use it. In many institutions the texts of previous examinations are *made available* for students to review so that they will have some idea of what sort of questions are asked and will know what they need to study.

In this case it appears that although other parts of old exams (short-answer and essay questions) were made available for students, the old multiple-choice exams were not--probably because designing a good multiple-choice exam is very time-consuming and the examiners didn't want to have to write an entire new set of questions and answers for the current exams.